# wordpress multisite - multiple registeration

Tags: php, wordpress

On a wp multiste, I would like users to be able to register on one site with the ability to register on the other sites with their existing account. Any suggestions?

Or what plugins should I be looking at?

I've tried...
MP-Members
Members
s2Members

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this!

Thank you.

P.S. 
I don't want users to be registered across all sites by default.

Comment: Run a script that copies the data in the other databases when the user asks for it on one site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress multisite, the feature that you want is already available. 
Try this out.
In Add New User screen, there are two options, Add Existing User and Add New User. 
From Add Existing User, the user of one site can be registered on another site with same email account with required role. 
Reply back, if the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

The only pretty solution I've ever found to this problem is the WPMU DEV [WordPress User Synchronization](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-user-synchronization/) plugin. It works perfectly for this problem.